# Swift 3: Calculation Field Error

Tags: swift

**** UPDATED ****

The latest saga has me still confused. As advised i sequenced the code as per the mathmatical calculations. I am still however getting a run error as before. Please see attached..

```
@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstValue = Double(ZFWinput.text!)
    let secondValue = Double(TotalFuelinput.text!)
    let thirdValue = Double(TripFuelinput.text!)

    let TFO000 = Double(secondValue!)
    let TFO004 = Double(secondValue! * 1.004)
    let TFO006 = Double(secondValue! * 1.006)
    let TFO007 = Double(secondValue! * 1.007)
    let TFO010 = Double(secondValue! * 1.01)
    let TFO011 = Double(secondValue! * 1.011)
    let TFO012 = Double(secondValue! * 1.012)

    let TripF000 = Double(thirdValue!)
    let TripF004 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.004)
    let TripF006 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.006)
    let TripF007 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.007)
    let TripF010 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.10)
    let TripF011 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.11)
    let TripF012 = Double (thirdValue! * 1.12)


    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for Total Fuel Adjustment with various TDP Loaded

    if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO011)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO010)"
    }
    else if aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO006)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO007)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO004)"
    }
    else {TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO000)"}


    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for Trip Fuel Adjust with various TDP Loaded

    if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF012)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF012)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF011)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF010)"
    }
    else if aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF006)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF007)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF004)"
    }
    else {TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF000)"}

    //----
    let fourthValue = Double(TotalFuelOutput2.text!)
    let fifthValue = Double(TripFuelOutput2.text!)

    let RampWeight1 = Double(firstValue! + secondValue!)
    let TOW1 = Double(RampWeight1 - 1)
    let LMass1 = (TOW1 - thirdValue!)

    let RampWeight2 = Double(firstValue! + fourthValue!)
    let TOW2 = Double(RampWeight2 - 1)
    let LMass2 = (TOW2 - fifthValue!)

    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for center figuers with no TDP adjustments

    RampOutput1.text = "\(RampWeight1)"
    TOWOutput1.text = "\(TOW1)"
    LandOutput1.text = "\(LMass1)"

    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for right hand side figures using new TotalFuelOutput2 & TripFuelOutput2

    RampOutput2.text = "\(RampWeight2)"
    TOWOutput2.text = "\(TOW2)"
    LandOutput2.text = "\(LMass2)"


}
```

I run the program and check the inputs. The first three are correct then it then jumps next to fourthValue before running the calculations as per the order above. I have attached the screenshot below.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCi2f.png)

A runtime error in the code is also below with the correct TFO012 result.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdNEM.png)

fourthValue should = the TFO012 value of 101.2, but in the list its 2.16095795579922694E-314. Where has it received this number from?

Again sorry for all the questions to you all. You have already been a HUGE help to me and if seriously appreciated!!

@Sam M, this is the full view controller code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TDP Calculator
//
//  Created by Ryan Harris on 24/09/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Harris. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var mainbutton: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var fwdbutton: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var aftbutton: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet var maindeckimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var fwdholdimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var aftholdimage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var ZFWinput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var TotalFuelinput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var TripFuelinput: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var RampOutput1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var TOWOutput1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var LandOutput1: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Calculate: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var ZFWOutput2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var TotalFuelOutput2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var RampOutput2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var TOWOutput2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var TripFuelOutput2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var LandOutput2: UILabel!

//Switches linked to all cargo bays on profile

@IBAction func maindeckswitch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if mainbutton.isOn {
        maindeckimage.isHidden = true
        mainbutton.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }else{
        maindeckimage.isHidden = false
        mainbutton.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }

}


@IBAction func fwdholdswitch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if fwdbutton.isOn {
        fwdholdimage.isHidden = true
        fwdbutton.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }else{
        fwdholdimage.isHidden = false
        fwdbutton.setOn(true, animated: true)
}

}


@IBAction func aftholdswitch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if aftbutton.isOn {
        aftholdimage.isHidden = true
        aftbutton.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }else{
        aftholdimage.isHidden = false
        aftbutton.setOn(true, animated: true)
    }


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Remove Keyboard with background Touch - Ryan Harris

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTapView))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

}

//Link function to Keyboard removal

func didTapView(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



// Calculation Code Starts here

@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstValue = Double(ZFWinput.text!)
    let secondValue = Double(TotalFuelinput.text!)
    let thirdValue = Double(TripFuelinput.text!)

    let TFO000 = Double(secondValue!)
    let TFO004 = Double(secondValue! * 1.004)
    let TFO006 = Double(secondValue! * 1.006)
    let TFO007 = Double(secondValue! * 1.007)
    let TFO010 = Double(secondValue! * 1.01)
    let TFO011 = Double(secondValue! * 1.011)
    let TFO012 = Double(secondValue! * 1.012)

    let TripF000 = Double(thirdValue!)
    let TripF004 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.004)
    let TripF006 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.006)
    let TripF007 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.007)
    let TripF010 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.10)
    let TripF011 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.11)
    let TripF012 = Double (thirdValue! * 1.12)


    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for Total Fuel Adjustment with various TDP Loaded

    if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO011)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO010)"
    }
    else if aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO006)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO007)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO004)"
    }
    else {TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO000)"}


    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for Trip Fuel Adjust with various TDP Loaded

    if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF012)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF012)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF011)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF010)"
    }
    else if aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF006)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF007)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF004)"
    }
    else {TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF000)"}

    //----
    let fourthValue = Double(TotalFuelOutput2.text!)
    let fifthValue = Double(TripFuelOutput2.text!)

    let RampWeight1 = Double(firstValue! + secondValue!)
    let TOW1 = Double(RampWeight1 - 1)
    let LMass1 = (TOW1 - thirdValue!)

    let RampWeight2 = Double(firstValue! + fourthValue!)
    let TOW2 = Double(RampWeight2 - 1)
    let LMass2 = (TOW2 - fifthValue!)

    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for center figuers with no TDP adjustments

    RampOutput1.text = "\(RampWeight1)"
    TOWOutput1.text = "\(TOW1)"
    LandOutput1.text = "\(LMass1)"

    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for right hand side figures using new TotalFuelOutput2 & TripFuelOutput2

    RampOutput2.text = "\(RampWeight2)"
    TOWOutput2.text = "\(TOW2)"
    LandOutput2.text = "\(LMass2)"


}




}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know how the lines you specified for fourthValue and fifthValue do not work. Does the code not compile? Or do you get a runtime error? And in either case, what is the error?

Comment: Appologies, i get a runtime error on line...... let RampWeight2 = Double(firstValue! + fourthValue!) saying THRED 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. Be sure you update your question with the actual code causing the error.

Comment: @RyanHK Is your problem fixed or are you still having a problem?

Comment: @Sam M still having problems unfortunatly. The latest was edited into the above post. Your update certainly helped but for some reason the fourthValue is still coming up with a randomnumber. I uploaded some screenshots above.

Comment: Getting a crash on `TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"` is very unusual, please update your question with your full code for this viewController so I can help you further.

Comment: @Sam M ... I have looked after a good 12 hours of sleep as it is totally my fault as a new guy to xcode. The IBOutlet var TotalFuelOutput2 for somereason lost its link to my storyboard !! Thank you again so much for your help before though as resolved someting else I did not understand. Your a star!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring and using `fourthValue` and `fifthValue` in your calculations before setting `TripFuelOutput2.text` and `TotalFuelOutput2.text` values. You should move the declaration and calculations involving `fourthValue` and `fifthValue` after all the if-elses so `TripFuelOutput2.text` and `TotalFuelOutput2.text` values have been set.

Modify your code like this:

```
@IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let firstValue = Double(ZFWinput.text!)
    let secondValue = Double(TotalFuelinput.text!)
    let thirdValue = Double(TripFuelinput.text!)

    let TFO000 = Double(secondValue!)
    let TFO004 = Double(secondValue! * 1.004)
    let TFO006 = Double(secondValue! * 1.006)
    let TFO007 = Double(secondValue! * 1.007)
    let TFO010 = Double(secondValue! * 1.01)
    let TFO011 = Double(secondValue! * 1.011)
    let TFO012 = Double(secondValue! * 1.012)

    let TripF000 = Double(thirdValue!)
    let TripF004 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.004)
    let TripF006 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.006)
    let TripF007 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.007)
    let TripF010 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.10)
    let TripF011 = Double(thirdValue! * 1.11)
    let TripF012 = Double (thirdValue! * 1.12)


    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for Total Fuel Adjustment with various TDP Loaded

    if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO012)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO011)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO010)"
    }
    else if aftbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO006)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO007)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn {
        TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO004)"
    }
    else {TotalFuelOutput2.text = "\(TFO000)"}


    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for Trip Fuel Adjust with various TDP Loaded

    if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF012)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF012)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && fwdbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF011)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn && aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF010)"
    }
    else if aftbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF006)"
    }
    else if fwdbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF007)"
    }
    else if mainbutton.isOn {
        TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF004)"
    }
    else {TripFuelOutput2.text = "\(TripF000)"}

    //----
    let fourthValue = Double(TotalFuelOutput2.text!)
    let fifthValue = Double(TripFuelOutput2.text!)

    let RampWeight1 = Double(firstValue! + secondValue!)
    let TOW1 = Double(RampWeight1 - 1)
    let LMass1 = (TOW1 - thirdValue!)

    let RampWeight2 = Double(firstValue! + fourthValue!)
    let TOW2 = Double(RampWeight2 - 1)
    let LMass2 = (TOW2 - fifthValue!)

    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for center figuers with no TDP adjustments

    RampOutput1.text = "\(RampWeight1)"
    TOWOutput1.text = "\(TOW1)"
    LandOutput1.text = "\(LMass1)"

    // *Self Reminder* Calculation for right hand side figures using new TotalFuelOutput2 & TripFuelOutput2

    RampOutput2.text = "\(RampWeight2)"
    TOWOutput2.text = "\(TOW2)"
    LandOutput2.text = "\(LMass2)"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the values returned by the text fields.  Make sure they are not nil, and are properly convertible to numbers in the proper range for double floats, starting with the first character (no leading whitespace, etc.).  Or else the Double() conversion might throw an error.